# Display relevant tag badges next to posts

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges, posting

Each question has some tags. If a user asking a question or posting an answer has tag badges that match the tags used in the question, can those tag badges be displayed next to the user?

For example, if a question has `c#` and  `winforms` tags, a user who has `c#` silver tag would have this tag displayed next to their answer.

This way it would give everyone more information about how much experience people who post have on specific topics. Also, that would make tag badges more relevant.

I can think of one possible problem though. Answers could be upvoted/accepted more on users' badges than on merit.